# Flex column children height calculation is off in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am using a UI library's tab control and am having trouble with IE.  When the number of tabs causes the container to scroll, the flex children's height does not appear to get calculated correctly in IE.  If I cause a repaint by editing a style or resizing the window, then it adjusts correctly.  Oddly, loading the attach HTML file via a file:/// URL, if you refresh it many times, I've noticed that it does render correctly sometimes.  But not very often.  All other browsers render this properly every time.

I've tried every kind of flex setting combination that I can think of however nothing seems to help.

```
I don't have any simple markup to provide unfortunately
```

See a CodePen here for the HTML and CSS - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqrBGV.

Screenshot of the issue as I see it - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1okzw2qjgPMr-LVsr_-Z-GXE28x2KAueG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please inform us, Which version of IE you are using? I try to make a test with IE 11 and find that It runs your code without any issue. Here is a testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/nrph4wqq/5.gif Let me know, If I miss anything in your above description. I will try to correct my self.

Comment: I have been using IE 11.  And if it helps any, the HTML in the document is actually populated using mithrilJS's render method.  I just saved out the outerHTML of the document to provide here.

Comment: Updated the OP to include a link to a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: I can see that there is a lot of CSS code in your example. Is that whole code is required by your web page or it is unnecessary? For testing purpose, Try to remove unnecessary CSS code and check whether it solves your issue or not.